# How to use "binding key" e.g for topics in AMQP.net lite library

Tags: c#, amqp

I'm using amqp.net lite to send messages to an AMQP 1.0 broker (qpid, rabbitmq with 1.0 plugin).

I'd like to send to a topic and want to add a "binding key" like described in the qpid docs (s. http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-7.1.0/book/Java-Broker-Concepts-Exchanges.html#Java-Broker-Concepts-Exchanges-Types-Topic) to route my message to a specific queue. Where and how do I specify a binding key like the "weather" in the example link?

How do I do that with amqpnetlite?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found the solution to my question. AMQP 1.0 does not know about the concept of exchanges. It's a pre-1.0 thing. Nevertheless some of the multi protocol brokers like Qpid are able to bring exchanges to AMQP 1.0.

So dealing with exchanges in AMQP 1.0 seems to be dependent on the broker.

Qpid expects the exchange in the address (where you normally would put the destination queue) and uses the message subject as routing key / binding.

The AMQP 1.0 <-> 0-9-1 mapping table on the RabbitMQ AMQP 1.0 plug-in page on Github was of great help: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0